# programming assignment using pycharm for school

Tags: python

I need help clearing this error.

“End of statement expected:”

This is my code listed below. I tried different things.  But I am new to coding.

```py
Output_list =[] for temperature in temperatures:
```

Comment: What's inside your loop? Looks like nothing, which is not valid Python.

Comment: try Output_list = [ temperature for temperature in temperatures ]

Answer (score 1):

You have not added any functionality to your for loop

```
Output_list =[] 
for temperature in temperatures: 
    Output_list.append(temperature)
```

This an example of how you can add the temperatures to the Output_List. Is this what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to solve the problem with list comprehension then here is the right way to do it

```py
outout_list = [temperature for temperature in temperatures]
```

or you can alternatively do this

```
Output_list =[] 

for temperature in temperatures: 
    Output_list.append(temperature)
```

in both cases you are basically adding all the temperatures in output_list